# combining results of CTEs

Tags: postgresql, count, common-table-expression

I have several CTEs. CTE1A counts number of type A shops in area 1. CTE1B counts number of type B shops in area 1 and so on up to CTE1D. Similarly, CTE2B counts number of type B shops in area 2 and so on. shop_types CTE selects all types of shops: A,B,C,D. How to display a table that shows for each area (column) how many shops of each type there is (rows). 
For example:

```
    1    2    3    4    5
A   0    7    4    0    0
B   2    3    8    2    9
C   8    5    8    1    6
D   7    1    5    4    3
```

Database has 2 tables:

Table regions: shop_id, region_id

Table shops: shop_id, shop_type

```
WITH 
shop_types AS (SELECT DISTINCT shops.shop_type AS type FROM shops WHERE shops.shop_type!='-9999' AND shops.shop_type!='Other'),
cte1A AS (
SELECT regions.region_id, COUNT(regions.shop_id) AS shops_number, shops.shop_type
FROM regions
RIGHT JOIN shops
ON shops.shop_id=regions.shop_id
WHERE regions.region_id=1
AND shops.shop_type='A'
GROUP BY shops.shop_type,regions.region_id)
SELECT * FROM cte1A
```

Comment: Why do you use so many CTEs to count this? You can probably do this with conditional counting in a single statement. But you have provided no sample input data, no table structures and you also forgot to provide your current query - this makes this impossible to answer.

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope now it's clearer. The database is what I have provided and can't modify it. Similarly, I got the queries written as they were used already in other place, but now I need to visualize the results in one table as described in the question.

Comment: unrelated, but: your outer join (in `cte1a`) isn't an outer join because you have a `where`  condition on the outer joined table. You are also not using the first cte `shop_types` in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand why you are after, but it seems you are looking for something like this:

```
select sh.shop_type, 
       count(case when r.region_id = 1 then 1 end) as region_1_count,
       count(case when r.region_id = 2 then 1 end) as region_2_count,
       count(case when r.region_id = 3 then 1 end) as region_3_count
from shops sh
  left join regions r on r.shop_id = sh.shop_id
group by sh.shop_type
order by sh.shop_type;
```

You need to add one `case` statement for each region you want to have in the output.

If you are using Postgres 9.4 you can replace the case statements using a `filter` condition which kind of makes the intention a bit easier to understand (I think)

```
count(*) filter (where r.region_id = 1) as region_1_count,
count(*) filter (where r.region_id = 2) as region_2_count, 
...
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/98391/1

---

And before you ask: no you can't make the number of columns "dynamic" based on a select statement. The column list for a query must be defined *before* the statement is actually executed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and sample query, but I can't use LEFT JOIN as you suggested, because shops table doesn't have region_id. The tables are connected by shop_ids. region_id is only in table regions.

Comment: @krltos: I don't use the `region_id` for the join, I use the `shop_id` (I fixed that a couple of minutes ago)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Shouldn't have been thinking on using ready queries, but write from scratch.